# TextView not showing up on a button

Tags: java, android

When I am trying to put text in a textView, which is inside of a button it does not show up when I run the app, what should I do? Below is an example:

[This image shows an example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8naeA.png)

[This is what I want to final output to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUUXB.png)

[On all of the buttons between the field area text and the opponent Trench Button, there are supposed to be 0s showing up in the top left of the button, but it isn't showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf4ik.png)

Comment: A TextView inside a button??? And also, post your code as text here, not screenshots

Comment: You are using FramLayout, inside FramLayout children are placed over one another. your Buttons height is match_parent so the TextView hides below the Button. Put your TextView out of the Framlayout.

Answer (score 0):

Because the layout element you are using is FrameLayout, which will make your element be covered by the next element, you can use LinearLayout or ConstraintLayout instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is FrameLayout which can show a single view at a time because the most recent view will be overlap on the other view. You can use another layout like as RelativeLayout, LinearLayout or ContraintLayout to achieve the desired output.

If you have only few views which you want to show horizontally/vertically then use LinearLayout else use Relative/Constraint Layout.